# ie9 vs ie10 compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Our site currently works in ie9 and we are considering what we need to do to make sure it works in ie10. I have 2 questions based on that

1>If I upgrade to ie10, would the f12 ie 9 browser mode be a good enough substitute for ie9? Or do I have to have a separate VM with ie9 to be absolutely sure it looks good in it.

2>What should I specifically be looking for in the HTML code that worked in ie 9 but won't work in ie 10?

Comment: I've always regarded "Internet Explorer compatibility" as an oxymoron.

Comment: I am also interested in this question. Our application ran without a hitch on IE7-9. IE10 for some reason inconsistently turns-on compatibility mode and causes a number of jQuery UI widgets to break. IE10 is definitely not the same as IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, if it works in older versions of IE without using hacks, then it will work in newer versions too.

IE's compatibility modes have improved some, so now it will actually pretend to not support things in the browser mode you set it to (such as not supporting `border-radius` in IE8 mode, or `JSON` in IE7 mode), so I believe it is a "good enough" substitute. However, there'll undoubtedly be that one something you can't pin down, so I would suggest setting up a VM with IE9 if you can.

Side-note: Be sure to include `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to avoid nasty surprises.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I've come accross is that IE10 compatibility mode breaks when setting non standard element attributes.

Documented here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12577
and here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/774078

That means code like this will cause a `member not found` error, because IE7 doesn't support the 'placeholder' attribute. This is a major problem if using jQueryUI

```
var input = jQuery( "<input>" )
            .appendTo( 'body')
            .val("Look at me")
            .attr("placeholder", "type something"); //setting placeholder attr will error
```